# CSS3 - a:hover background image not working online (but works with a:active)

Tags: css, background, hover

So, I have a nav menu in my header with the following code for hover on a items:

```
header nav ul li a:hover {
color: #a1c0f4;
padding-top: 30px;
background: url('../images/tinychokurei.png') top center no-repeat;
}
```

I also have an a:active:

```
header nav ul li a:active {
color: #0c00ff;
padding-top: 25px;
background: url('../images/tinychokurei.png') top center no-repeat;
}
```

When I browse the site offline, it works fine, but when I go online, the hover only changes the color of the text, but does not display the image. The image is uploaded as it is the same exact file for my a:active function and it spawns OK, so I am a little lost, lol.

Comment: We need to see a bit more of your CSS, are there any other styles that may be overwriting it?

Answer (score 0):

I changed the padding to 35px and it works fine... go figure!